# Subring of Z[x] with ACCP property

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

> I have the subring of $\mathbb Z[x]$ with $f(1/2)$ always an integer. I have to check if it has ACCP (Ascending Chain Condition on Principal ideals) property or not.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The WHAT property? So far I've found ACCP = Ambulatory Care Pharmacy Ambulatory, or ACCP= American College of Chest Physicians...please be clear in your questions, think that not all come from the same university and not even from the same country. (I, of course, assume you meant Ascending Chain Condiniton (on) Principal Ideals, but still...)

Comment: Yes Sorry about that ACCP = Ascending chain condition on Principal ideals

Comment: I think you want to say "the subring of $\mathbb Q[x]$". If this is the case then the answer is negative.